# How to Transfer Umbraco CMS from One PC to Another

Tags: umbraco

I am newbie with Umbraco.

I get the source code copy from my Vendor. I want to run UmbracoCMS on my local Development PC.

I changed connectionstring and point to database which provided by vendor.

When I run the UmbracoCMS it gives me this error. How to fix this? Which settings do I need to make to run on my local system?

Error:

```
e.Fields["umbracoFileName"] = Path.GetFileName(e.Fields["umbracoFile"]);
```

Comment: Check if /media/ folder is on your PC. Check if IUSR has read/write rights to the folder where Umbraco is placed.

Comment: It solved by giving rights to IUSR to the complete project folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try republishing all your nodes by visiting
    http://YOURDOMAIN/Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?previews=true
and also chack the the /media/ folders exists and all the permission for the user that runs the app pool are set right